# Enable nView Desktop Manager on startup

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

I have nView Desktop Manager 146.33 installed on my computer, and I use it to manage windows across my screens. However, I have to manually open and enable it every time my computer is booted. Is there a way to automatically enable nView on startup?

Answer (score 1):

Just put a shortcut of the needed executable file or files in the following path:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: What executable is that?  I don't see any `exe` files in the nView directory.

Answer (score 0):

You make the nView executable into a service.

To do this you need to open powershell and run:
sc create nService binPath= "c:/program files/etc"

Then head into services.msc and set it to 'automatic'.

Comment: Which executable should I use? As far as I can tell I can only access nView through the right-click menu on the desktop. `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nview` contains 3 .exe files: nwiz, nvAppBar, and nvTaskbar. None of those opens the same app I see when I right-click the desktop and select nView Desktop Manager.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, nView was located at `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nview\nvwdmcpl.dll", nViewMain`

I found this by:

1. finding nView Desktop Manager link in my start menu.
2. right-clicking -> Properties
3. copy the information from `Target`
4. I notice that `Start in` has `"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nview"`