# How can one make multiple custom "desktops" (Win+Tab) in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

Windows 10 brings many new useful features and the option of having 'Desktops' is one of them. However, this feature is very limited. I would like to know if you can do the following:
1. Give each 'desktop' a different background
2. Give each 'desktop' a different "desktop" folder so they can have different folders/files on their desktop (as in the files the show on the background)
3. Give each 'desktop' a custom name (instead of desktop1/desktop2)
4. Give each 'desktop' a different color setting
I have tried searching this online, the only pages I found were about windows 7 not 10.
Any piece of software will help.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1537713/1062246 - We can give custom names, the others are not possible as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the biggest thing to mention with Windows 10 "desktops" is that they are really just "virtual" desktops. They really provide functionality to separate programs into logical groups to help organize the desktop, not give you customizable desktops or named desktops as you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This stinks. Not the answer, the fact that it is so limited.

Comment: Well without the use of third party software, you have no way of doing this.

Comment: But do you know any software that can do this?

Comment: That's not what you asked tho. You said you would like to know how you can do this, implying you wanted to know how to do this with Windows 10, not any third party software. I don't use any desktop manager software, so i can't suggest any.

Comment: @LukeFarnell actually the OP did ask about software: "I have tried searching this online, the only pages I found were about windows 7 not 10. Any piece of software will help." <--Direct quote from question.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 you can now atleast rename your windows desktops.
Shift + Tab. Then right click and rename that desktop.
The names will survive as long as you don't close those desktops, i.e. they survive a restart typically.