# name desktop in Windows 10 Taskview

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-view

How do I name each desktop within the Windows 10 Taskview?

If I click the Taskview button on the Taskbar [image] then the view zooms out from the current desktop.

A top bar shows the available desktops.
I have two Taskview desktops named *Desktop 1* and *Desktop 2*.  I would like useful names for the desktops; e.g. *Gaming*, or *Project ABC*, or *Work*, etcetera.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change name of Virtual Desktop in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/959258/change-name-of-virtual-desktop-in-windows-10)

Comment: @Valay_17 good link but "no", I am still unable to name the Windows virtual desktops.

Comment: Please read the answer carefully, it clearly says it is an windows insider feature currently and it will be released later to the other consumers. If you wish to become an insider, a link is provided in the accepted answer.